# Desktop Launcher File Not Working as Intended

Tags: launcher, lts

I have installed 'Peek' Gif Recorder on Ubuntu 22.04.

The application launches and will start recording, but once I stop the recording it crashes.

I have found that running `peek -b ffmpeg` in the terminal resolves this issue, and I'm able to use the application as intended.

I don't want to have to run a command every time I start the application, so I created an identical Desktop Launcher file in my `~/.local/share/applications` folder. The only difference between this local Desktop Launcher file and the default Desktop Launcher file for this application in `/usr/share/applications` is the Exec field value. I have changed this to be `peek -b ffmpeg`. I have also changed the name to 'Peek t' just for testing purposes.

The application desktop icon name is now 'Peek t', but the issue is that this application refuses to work when using the launcher still, and I don't understand why. If `peek -b ffmpeg` runs the application just fine from the terminal, then why would it not work correctly for the desktop launcher?

Here is the contents of the newly created local desktop launcher file I created:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=Peek t
Exec=/usr/bin/peek -b ffmpeg
Icon=com.uploadedlobster.peek
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
DBusActivatable=true
```

Comment: I do not know why that would not work. Could you test following Exec= line: `Exec=sh -c "/usr/bin/peek -b ffmpeg"`

Comment: @vanadium Unfortunately, that did not work.

Comment: I only succeed in recording black screens each time. Only the cursor is visible in the rendered gif. I use Wayland, and apparently this application only supports X11, which you probably are using if you can succesfully record. It will be useful to add that information to your question (including also info on your graphical card). That said, I have no problem launching it using a desktop launcher instead of terminal. Specifying --backend gnome-shell give an error, so I guess that for me, the tool automatically selects ffmpeg as backend when no option is provided.